# modifying my feynman digram: drawing square and lines coming out of it

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, feynman, feynmp-auto

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{feynman}
\node[shape=circle,draw=black, inner sep=0pt,minimum size=20pt] (m) at ( 0, 0) {};
\node[shape=rectangle,fill=black] (n) at (3, 0) {square };
\vertex (a) at ( 210:2cm) {};
\vertex (b) at ( -30:2cm) {};
\vertex (c) at (150:2cm) {};
\vertex (d) at (30:2cm) {};      
        
\diagram* {
(a) -- [photon,edge label'=$q_2$] (m) 
-- [photon,edge   label'=$q_1$] (c),
(n) -- [bend left=45, edge label=$\pi^+(K^+)$] (m)
-- [bend left=45, edge label=$\pi^-(K^-)$] (n),
};
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

I have three questions:

1. How can we make the rectangle, a square?
2. How can we make the curves lines enter the square at the two vertices in the left?
3. How can we create two straight lines come out of the other two vertices of the square in right?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have a look at the answers to this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/674051/245790 . // Suggestion: Consider searching this site next time.

Comment: Ok. You‘ll find all answers to your 3 questions in the tikz manual (the big one). To simplify this task, I suggest to discard all feynman speak for a while. E.g. a vertex in feynman speak is a path in tikz speak. Have a try or two on the tikz manual. With this transformation in mind you‘ll also find plenty of Q&A, here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. As you now have it, the node `(n)` contains the text "square", which is much wider than tall. You can make it square by adding a `\rule` there instead.
2. The above will take care of this one too, thanks to geometry...
3. You need two more vertices at coordinates calculated using node `n` as the origin. I called them `(e)` and `(f)`.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,calc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{feynman}
\node[shape=circle,draw=black,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=20pt] (m) at (0, 0) {};
\node[shape=rectangle,fill=black] (n) at (3, 0) {\rule{0.5cm}{0.5cm}};
\vertex (a) at (225:2cm) {};
\vertex (b) at (-45:2cm) {};
\vertex (c) at (135:2cm) {};
\vertex (d) at (45:2cm) {};
\vertex (e) at ($(n) + (-45:2cm)$) {};
\vertex (f) at ($(n) + (45:2cm)$) {};

\diagram*{
(a) -- [photon,edge label'=$q_2$] (m)
-- [photon,edge   label'=$q_1$] (c),
(n) -- [bend left=45, edge label=$\pi^+(K^+)$] (m)
-- [bend left=45, edge label=$\pi^-(K^-)$] (n),
(e) -- (n) -- (f),
};
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I also changed the angles of the lines to 45 degrees, instead of 30, otherwise the lines exiting the black square will not fall on the vertices (again, because geometry).

The result is shown below:

[image: result]

Comment: Add `draw=black` to node `(n)`. It won't be perfect (if you zoom more) but I think it will be OK.

Comment: The label is too large to fit on the edge where you want it (or at least, that's what tikz thinks). Change all "2cm" to "3cm" and place node `(n)` at (4, 0). This way you'll make the diagram larger, the edge label will be relatively smaller and will fit in the middle of the curved line.